# How to use Data Factory to ingest all Dynamics 365 entities to a Data Lake?

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm, azure-data-lake

I'm currently using a Data Factory (V2) to copy a few entities from Dynamics 365 to an Azure Data Lake (Gen1).

So far I've just been creating each sink dataset individually as they become relevant. But there are hundreds of potential entities to copy and setting that up with my current process will be ridiculously time consuming.

Is it possible (or is there a better way) to copy all the entities to a data lake?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the Dynamics 365 Data Export Service is helpful in your Case. It allows you to easly Export Dynamics 365 Tables to Azure SQL. I never done it by myself, but it seems very easy to Setup. Maybe it is easier to move stuff from an Azure SQL DB into the DataLake.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/admin/replicate-data-microsoft-azure-sql-database

https://community.dynamics.com/365/b/dynamicspeople/archive/2017/05/29/dynamics-365-data-export-service-with-azure-sql-database

Comment: It's not the answer I was hoping for but we've decided to go this route.

Comment: We tried the Data Export Service and it is very error prone and impossible to troubleshoot. So we're still looking for a solution

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft have just announced an export to data lake feature that may help with your scenario. It's currently in preview.

https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/exporting-cds-data-to-azure-data-lake-preview/

Comment: This is better suited as a comment, rather than an answer.